# BlackBerry Android installation

Tags: android, blackberry

How to install and run the Android `.apk` file in BlackBerry.

What are the step i should follow?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently not possible because Android OS is not portable to a Blackberry device...

Comment: sorry I don't understand... what?

Comment: List some mobile phone names supports android application .

Comment: hm... why does the `Android Application` are called `Android Application`? Because they only run on `Android` devices. So buy a device which has android already installed...

Comment: iphone support android application or not, And before buy mobile we should ask android will work on this or How exactly ?

Comment: http://www.androidmobilephone.com/   http://www.honeytechblog.com/android-phones/    http://www.honeytechblog.com/android-phones/

Comment: see all these mobile tooo high end price mobile,

Comment: What is so difficult on the fact, that Android Application can only run on the Android OS?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you develop for blackberry 10. You need to repackage your apk to a blackberry bar file. You can use an Eclipse Plugin, command line tools or even an online tool to do so.
[This](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/gettingstarted.html) should get you started.

Comment: So I guess you voted me down? Great, take a look at the date of my answer! It was two years ago!

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't vote you down but your question, as it is outdated by now.

Comment: Well what a coincident that you answered 3 minutes after the down vote happened...

Comment: This question is clearly about the BlackBerry Java-ME platform, not BlackBerry-10.